# Remove File Explorer Toolbar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I setup a new Lenovo laptop and am seeing an unidentified toolbar in File Explorer. Shown below as the line below the address bar. I get a vertical drag icon, but cannot right-click it. How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is just the line below the ribbon and is part of Explorer. It is not removable and is much less pronounced in the Light View instead of Dark View.

You can collapse the ribbon to make it smaller and that may help you. (Upper right Up Arrow beside Help)

Comment: I'm referring to the line below the address bar. I've not seen this on any other Windows 10 installation.

Comment: That line is not removable.  I have checked several computers here including one at Windows 10 V2004